React Native Screens : JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION
I am getting the error :
"JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI GetObjectRefType called with pending exception java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for com.facebook.jni.HybridData com.swmansion.rnscreens.NativeProxy.initHybrid() (tried Java_com_swmansion_rnscreens_NativeProxy_initHybrid and Java_com_swmansion_rnscreens_NativeProxy_initHybrid__)"
when I try to run the build on an emulator, it opens the app and closes almost immediately,
I got the following error from looking at the emulator logs.
I am running the following dependancies:
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^7.0.3",
"@react-navigation/native": "^7.0.2",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^7.0.2",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.14.0",
"react-native-screens": "^4.1.0"
Can you please help with regards to what this error means and where I should look to fix it ?
I ran through the installation guide again to check if I was missing anything.
